# Based on Cell Value, identify current row and copy the same row in 3 worksheets to a new workbook (in a loop) - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**The way my data is setup is as follows:**

Master Sheet:
Column A: Company Names (rows 1-100)
Column B: Flag? Y/N (rows 1-100)

Sheet2:
Column A: Company Names (rows 1-100 in the same order as Master Sheet)
Columns B-D: Data for each company (one company's data per row)

Sheet 3/4 are the same as Sheet2, just different data.

**What I'm trying to do:**
If on the Master Sheet Column B's value is "Y", then for that row, copy the same row from Sheets 2/3/4 into a new workbook.

**Example:**
In the Master Sheet, the first row with a "Y" value is row 6 (therefore, company#6). I would like to copy row 6 from sheets 2/3/4 into a new workbook with 4 sheets (Master Sheet row 6 only, Sheet2/3/4 row 6 only).

Repeat for all rows with a Y value.

The code I have so far:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, FileNm As String, LastRow As Long, wbTemp As Workbook, k As Long, currentRow As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook


With wb
    LastRow = .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End With


For k = 1 To LastRow
    FileNm = wb.Path & "\" & "BOOK" & k & ".xlsx" 'adding the i to number every workbook from 1 to number of rows

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add 'adding a new workbook

        If Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k,2).Value = "Y" Then

           currentRow = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Rows(k) 

    wb.Sheets(1).currentRow.Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(1).Rows(1)
    wb.Sheets(2).currentRow.Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(2).Rows(1)
    wb.Sheets(3).currentRow.Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(3).Rows(1)
    wb.Sheets(4).currentRow.Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(4).Rows(1)

End If
    wbTemp.SaveAs FileNm
    wbTemp.Close
    Set wbTemp = Nothing
Next k

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It's not working-- my guess is due to the line

```
currentRow = Worksheets("Master Sheet).Rows(k)
```

but I don't know how to work around that. Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's `Rows(11)` not `K`

Comment: You don't need the currentRow variable, it is already stored in `k`

Comment: Can you also ammend your question to `("Master Sheet").Rows`? You're missing a `"` and it's messing the rest of the snippet up

Comment: Why would it be row 11? Sorry just trying to understand. And I added the ", my bad! Thank you.

Comment: Because firstly, Rows are numbers and columns are letters - but also in vba, both are given numerical values. 
While typing this I realised you're using `k` as a variable - try hiding that line and running it again - what do you get?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the subscript?

Comment: The original code was "fine", which a small error. `If Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, 2).Value = "Y" Then`. After you use `Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add` The new workbook is the active workbook now, the If Worksheets will never find "master sheet" in it. Adding wb. to that line should fix the whole thing. `If wb.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, 2).Value = "Y" Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can do this inside another nested loop statement. No need to create a second variable to track the row you are on - your variable `k` already does this.

You will need to add `Dim j as Long` of course

```
For k = 1 To LastRow
    FileNm = wb.Path & "\" & "BOOK" & k & ".xlsx" 'adding the i to number every workbook from 1 to number of rows

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add 'adding a new workbook
        If Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k, 2).Value = "Y" Then
            For j = 1 To 4
                wb.Sheets(j).Row(k).Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(j).Rows(1)
            Next j
        End If

    wbTemp.SaveAs FileNm
    wbTemp.Close
    Set wbTemp = Nothing
Next k
```

Comment: This looks good! I'm trying to test it now, however I'm getting an error for the line "Nest j" -- I added the Dim j As Long already so I don't know what's causing that issue? It says Sub or Function not defined.

Comment: Are you trying to test this code as is? This needs to be put into your code replacing your loop

Comment: No I'm amending it to include in the rest of the code-- I realized that instead of Nest it should be Next! Will test now and report back.

Comment: I'm getting an error as soon as it opens the new workbook (and the code stops working then too); Run-time error 9, Subscript out of range.
What could be causing that?

Comment: When you share errors, you need to state exactly what line. That error could be on any line where you refer to a range object

Comment: I fixed the earlier error by making the line "If wb.Worksheets(...". Now I'm getting another error on the line under the J for loop: "wb.Sheets(j).Row(k).Copy...   the error is Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.  (thanks for all your help)

Comment: If it helps, I noticed that the error occurs after copying the row from the first sheet. I tried taking the copy function out of the loop and repeating it manually for sheets 1 through 4, and now the highlighted row for the same error message is the second row. It seems to copy the first set just fine, but it gets stuck when attempting to copy the second sheet's row.

Comment: I think I got to the root of the issue! When the new workbook is created, it only adds one sheet. When trying to copy the second sheet into it, it cannot find a "Sheet(2)" in the tempWB; would it be possible to create 4 sheets in the Workbooks.Add line?

Comment: Not sure - you could just nest that inside the `j` loop as well

Answer (score 0):

When copying to the new spreadsheet, you need to access the Rows property of the sheet.

```
wb.Sheets(3).Rows(currentRow).Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(3).Rows(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With much help from @urdearboy, reached this solution:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, FileNm As String, LastRow As Long, wbTemp As Workbook, k As Long, z As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 4 'must add this line for the nested loop to work

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    With wb
    LastRow = .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End With


For k = 1 To LastRow
    FileNm = wb.Path & "\" & "BOOK" & k & ".xlsx" 'adding the k to number every workbook from 1 to number of rows

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add 'adding a new workbook, will add 4 sheets

        If wb.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(k,2).Value = "Y" Then  'have to add "wb."

        For z = 1 To 4

        wb.Sheets(z).Rows(k).Copy Destination:=wbTemp.Sheets(z).Rows(k)

        Next z

End If
    wbTemp.SaveAs FileNm
    wbTemp.Close
    Set wbTemp = Nothing
Next k

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```